# "doGet request" on google script weebapp

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have an application on google scripts that worked perfectly. Between one deploy and another it stopped working loading my html page.

Yes, I have the doGet() function in the code:

```
function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('page');
}
```

This is page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Just a Heading</h1>
<p>a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Even with the file configured, whenever I open the generated url it is only displayed: doGet request, just that.

I copied the files to another project and it worked, but when I duplicated my project it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('page');` will show only `page`. In order use the HTML from the `page.html` file use `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page');`